# Using template arguments inside a lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm working with a map of functions for a simple language I'm developing, everything works fine but I'd like to provide a better way to define the numerical operators which works on numerical values in a more concise way.

The main problem is that I have something like:

```
using BinaryFunction = std::function<StackValue(StackValue,StackValue)>;

registerFunction("+", Type::FLOAT, {Type::FLOAT, Type::FLOAT}, BinaryFunction([](StackValue v1, StackValue v2) { return StackValue(v1.as<float>() + v2.as<float>()); }));
registerFunction("+", Type::FLOAT, {Type::FLOAT, Type::INT}, BinaryFunction([](StackValue v1, StackValue v2) { return StackValue(v1.as<float>() + v2.as<s32>()); }));
..
```

So basically for each operator that supports both `float` and `int` data types I must provide 4 functions which works with the possible combinations

```
int, int -> int
int, float -> float
float, int -> float
float, float -> float
```

Now I don't want to provide implicit type conversion so I'm fine in having 4 different functions for each combination but I'd like a way to define them all at once without having to repeat the code.

The problem is how I could do it, the main problem resides in the lambda:

```
[](StackValue v1, StackValue v2) { return StackValue(v1.as<float>() + v2.as<float>()); };
```

To be able to do what I need I'd need a way to parametrize the code with a template, something like

```
return StackValue(v1.as<T1>() + v2.as<T2>())
```

Then the correct specialization of `StackValue<T>(T)` takes care of the rest.

so that I can then do something like

```
registerNumericFunction(...)
{
  registerTemplate<float, float>(...);
  registerTemplate<s32, float>(...);
  ..
}
```

But I'm not finding a clever way to do it because I need to pass a lambda to the method which should be parametric. I don't know if it is possible at all.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: `enum Type : u8`, that's not a problem since I can use `std::conditional` to choose the correct one according to the two operator types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void registerTemplate() {
    registerFunction("+", Type::FLOAT, {Type::FLOAT, Type::FLOAT},
                     BinaryFunction([](StackValue v1, StackValue v2) {
                         return StackValue(v1.as<T1>() + v2.as<T2>());
                     }));
}

registerTemplate<float, float>();
registerTemplate<s32, float>();
```

---

Or this?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename Op>
BinaryFunction makeFunction(Op op) {
    return [op](StackValue v1, StackValue v2) {
        return StackValue(op(v1.as<T1>(), v1.as<T2>()));
    };
}
```

To be used as:

```
registerFunction("+", ..., makeFunction<float, float>(std::plus<>{}));
registerFunction("+", ..., makeFunction<s32, float>(std::plus<>{}));
```

It would really help if you actually make it clear in your question what it is you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: This parametrizes over the type of a specific lambda which is not what I'm looking for, not a generic lambda. The problem is that I have many operators (+, -, *, /, <, >, <=, == and so on) and I'd like to register each operator once but implicitly define it for all the combinations. Basically something like `registerTemplate<typename T1, typename T2, typename LAMBDA>`

Comment: @Jack So pass like `std::plus<>` in as another argument. I really don't understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: indeed I didn't know about `std::plus<>` and its friends existence, this definitely solves the problem.